# Forked child exits with -1, but WEXITSTATUS gets 255

Tags: c, exit

I exit with -1 in the child, but the parent picks up 255 instead. Is there a way to make the parent recognize -1 instead? Here is my code

```
  pid = fork();

  // if fork fails
  if (pid < 0){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (pid == 0){
    // purposely exit
    _exit(-1);
  }
  else{
    int status;
    int corpse = wait(&status);
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {
      int estat = WEXITSTATUS(status);
      if (estat == 0){
        printf("Command was successfully executed\n");
      }
      else{
        printf("Error: child exited with status %d\n", estat);
      }
    }
    else
      printf("signalled\n", corpse);
```

Comment: What is the type of the return variable in `WEXITSTATUS`?

Comment: Unsigned decimal integer? how can i convert it to -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html):

> `WEXITSTATUS(status)`
>
> returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the
>         least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child
>         specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument
>         for a return statement in main().  This macro should be
>         employed only if WIFEXITED returned true.

The least significant 8 bits of `-1` is `0xFF`(`255`).

Answer (score 0):

the status returned from function `wait` contains information of not only the exit code of the child process, but also contains the termination reason, etc.. thus, it is **impossible** to get the exact exit code of the child process, and only the least 8 bits of the child exiting code is represented.

Answer (score 0):

status will be 0xFF00 after wait().